# PHP/MySQL returns no result and no error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a single MySQL query created from PHP 5. The Query has 3 SELECT and 2 JOIN clauses. It accesses two databases on a single host using one connection and db1.table1 db2.table2 techniques. I echo the query before running. In PHP the query returns no result and does not error. When I copy and paste the echoed query into SQL in PHPMyAdmin, it returns the correct result.

Why is PHP different to the SQL part of PHPMyAdmin and does anyone have any suggestions about getting it to work in PHP?

Comment: Maybe the connection is not set properly. add  `or die(mysql_error())` to your `mysql_query` in the PHP file and tell what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is PHP different to the SQL part of PHPMyAdmin

It's not.

You're connecting to the wrong database, writing the wrong query, or checking for errors incorrectly.

Comment: I second that, definitely sounds like a Layer8 problem

Comment: Thanks folks, it is now working!@Balanivash: or die - it died!

Comment: Thanks folks, it is now working!                           @TomalakGeretkalh: "It's not" got me away from the query (which has taken an hour or two to get working) and on to the connexion. Connecting to the other database made it all work. I am still not sure what the difference is but I will leave the investigation for another day. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bobby: "The other database"? Well, if for some reason you have two databases, then one of them has no data in and that's why you got no result!